# How to change format of a date from dd/mm/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy where date is already converted from string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am getting date from a API which is in string format, I converted that string to date but unable to change it's format. Currently I got string like this -> '20/11/2016' I want to convert this & should look like this
-> 11/20/2016 & then only I can display this in html page using html 5 date input type

```
    <input type='date' ng-model='myDate'>

   myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$filter'],
   function ($scope,$filter)
   {
    //consider this string comes from api...
   var stringDate='20/11/2016';
   var convertedDate=new Date(stringDate);
   $scope.myDate=$filter('date')(convertedDate,'MM/dd/yyyy');
   });
```

Comment: Can you use momentjs ?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I'll try right now

Comment: rather than to use moment js , this filter can resolve this problem simply.

Comment: in this case $filter didn't works. if I console it displayed Invalid Date @Jigar7521

Comment: @Jigar7521  moment js works for me and it the best solution. thank you, man...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var stringDate1=this.dStartDate;
var splitDate1 = stringDate1.split('-');
var year1  = splitDate1[0];
var month1 = splitDate1[1];
var day1 = splitDate1[2];
this.dStartDate = month1+"-"+day1+"-"+year1;
console.log("date"+this.dStartDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove 'new' so

```
var stringDate='20/11/2016';
var convertedDate=new Date(stringDate);
```

should be

```
var stringDate='20/11/2016';
var convertedDate=Date(stringDate);
```

Comment: already converted in to date, want to change format to mm/dd/yyyy. final output should be 11/20/2016

Answer (score 1):

You can split and then pass to date object. After that using Date functions reform the date.

```
var dateArray = '31/12/2016'.split('/');
var convertedDate = new Date(dateArray[1]+'-'+dateArray[0]+' '+dateArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using momentjs

```
var convertedDate = moment('20/11/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Using vanilla javascript

```
var dateArray = '20/11/2016'.split('/');
var convertedDate = new Date(dateArray[1]+'-'+dateArray[0]+'-'+dateArray[2]);
```

Probably this is not the best implementation, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not give `stringDate` directly as input to Date object as it is not a valid Date string.

Revised code:

```
var stringDate='20/11/2016';
var splitDate = stringDate.split('/');
var convertedDate=new Date(splitDate[2], splitDate[1]-1, splitDate[0]);
console.log(convertedDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
$scope.myDate = convertedDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
```

Here using en-US locale returns 11/20/2016 format. You can find more about toLocale conversion [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx).

Comment: @VimalKumarBohara I have added line to update ng-model. Plz chk

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  var stringDate='20/11/2016';
  $scope.myDate=$filter('date')(stringDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```